# Как правильно создать / экспортировать класс

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Имеется класс, который создан для того, чтобы оперировать с моделями ORM.
То есть, есть созданные модели таблиц, их нужно поместить в класс, чтобы производить операции с ними.

Вопрос в том, можно ли так делать в принципе, как делаю я и почему у меня не получается сделать нормальный экспорт.

```
//На входе две модели Sequelize (то есть таблицы БД в виде классов)
const {People, City} = require('/path')
```

создаю класс:

```
class MainModel {
    constructor(people, city){
        this.people = people
        this.city = city
    }
//Далее я создаю метод, в котором получаю нужные мне значения из этих таблиц
    async getAll(){
       //тут специфический код sequelize и далее присваиваем res какое-то значение 
        const res = await this.people.findAll()
        return JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)
}


}
```

Далее я создаю экземпляр класса и экспортирую.

```
const newpeop = MainModel(People, City)
module.exports = newpeop
```

В файле роутинга я произвожу импорт из данного файла и хочу, чтобы при переходе на главную у меня выводился результат.

```
//в роутер файле

const mainModel = require(../path_to_model_file)
router.get('/', mainModel.getAllQuery())
```

По итогу получаю ошибки :
Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Promise]

И другие, в зависимости от того, что меняю.

В чем причина?
Понимаю, что указанная причина из-за получения промиса вместо значения, но не совсем понимаю, как это исправить.
Сразу извиняюсь за качество кода, я совсем новичок.

Comment: почитайте в документации что ждёт от вас инициализатор роутера. в ошибке вам пишут, что ожидается callback function, т.е. что-то вроде `router.get('/', async (req, res) => res.send(await mainModel.getAllQuery()))`

Comment: то, что вы - новичок, не оправдывает отсутствие интереса к документации http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#router.METHOD

Comment: Если пытаешься запихнуть мидлвэр-функцию в объект модели, то это смысловая ошибка. Модель не должна работать с сервером напрямую, это слишком много ответственности для нее. Разумнее будет создать объект мидлвэра использующий модели, а далее уже его экспортировать и подключать к Экспрессу (или к роутеру, при ветвистых эндпоинтах).